# Jqgrid: Get collapsed groups to be displayed on the same page

Tags: jqgrid

My grid contains a lot of data (>10,000 rows) and when grouping is enabled, the groups usually are too large to fit on a single page when expanded (for the sake of performance "rowNum" can only be set to 150 maximum).

Now, when all groups are collapsed I just get to see the first group on the first page, and I have to skip all the pages I would have to skip if the group was expanded to get to the next group. That way, it is rather difficult for the user to get an overview on all groups.

Is there any way to get the next group after a collapsed group to be displayed on the same page, regardless of how many rows the collapsed group comprises?

Answer (score 0):

**DISCLAIMER**: This is sort of a hack job!

In your collapse group button function, use `setGridParam` and set the `rowNum` property to a very high number:

```
$("#yourgrid").jqGrid('setGridParam', { rowNum: 1000000 }); // one million
```

In your expand group button function, reset the `rowNum` to a lesser value of your choosing:

```
$("#yourgrid").jqGrid('setGridParam', { rowNum: 150});
```

Comment: I tried that first, but it made the grid extremely slow (the data type is JSON). I use a lot of formatters and other methods that process the row data, so maybe that's why loading so many (or all) rows at once kills the performance. Do you have another idea, maybe how to load the rows without actually processing the data (and process it only once a group is expanded) so that the performance doesn't slow down?